# Call form values in form handler

Tags: symfony

Here is my problem.

I am curently learning Symfony and I have created a form with a formType file and a formHandler. 
I'd like now to use values of the form in my handler but I can't figure how to call those values, which method can I use? I've tried many method of the request class but it doesn't work.
Could you help me please?

Here is my handler. Some of my try are still in it commented, it's quiet simple, I'm just trying to do an echo.

```
class adminFormHandler
{
    protected $form;
    protected $request;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->form    = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em      = $em;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        if( $this->request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
        {
            $this->form->bindRequest($this->request);

            //if( $this->form->isValid() )
            //{
                //echo $this->request->get('nom');
                //$param = $this->request->request->keys();
                //$param = $this->form->getData(nom);
                //echo $param;
                $myfield = $form->getAttribute('nom');
                echo $myfield->getData();
                //echo $param;//$this->form->get('nom')->getText();
                //$this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());

                return true;
            //}
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function onSuccess1(/*Students $students*/)
    {
        //$this->em->persist($students);
        //$this->em->flush();
        echo'on success 1';
    }

    public function onSuccess2()
    {
        //$this->em->persist($students);
        //$this->em->flush();
        echo'on success 2';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more details about your code, specifically the form handler

Comment: I've just edit my first question. I've just registered today on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$data = $this->form->getData();
$myfield = $data['nom'];
```

or

```
$myfield = $this->form->get('nom')->getData();
```

Comment: You should read more carefully the documentation. I just got these two pieces of info from the forms chapter in the symfony book

Comment: And if the answer works for you, you should accept it so that other people know it has been answered to your satisfaction